# Parsing dissimilar Json data into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this Json just below which I want to parse into an array as shown further down

```
 const uiSchema = {
      "c1": {
        "ApplicantTitle": {
          "ui:widget": "text"
        },
        "ApplicantSurname": {
          "ui:widget": "text"
        },
        "ApplicantGender": {
          "ui:widget": "select"
        }
      },
      "c2": {
        "Tenure": {
          "ui:widget": "select"
        },
        "MovedToAddressDate": {
          "ui:widget": "date"
        }
      },
      "c3": {
        "Pregnant": {
          "ui:widget": "select"
        },
        "PregnantDueDate": {
          "ui:widget": "date"
        },
        "ParentGuardianChildUnder19": {
          "ui:widget": "select"
        },
      },
      "_unmapped": {
        "ApplicantForenames": {
          "ui:widget": "text"
        },
        "ApplicantDateOfBirth": {
          "ui:widget": "date"
        }
      }
    }
```

What I'd like is an array something like

```
uiParsed[0] =  
   "ApplicantTitle": {
      "ui:widget": "text"
    },
    "ApplicantSurname": {
      "ui:widget": "text"
    },
    "ApplicantGender": {
      "ui:widget": "select"
    }

uiParsed[1] =  
    "Tenure": {
      "ui:widget": "select"
    },
    "MovedToAddressDate": {
      "ui:widget": "date"
    }

the other uiParsed[] elements
```

I've tried to loop round but I can't just hard code c1, c2 etc as I could have any number of c types  c-nth, also the last Json "_unmapped" throws a spanner in the works.

If any one can't suggest a solution, cheers, I can use Lodash BTW.

Comment: var uiParsed = _.values(uiSchema) will do your job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like.

```js
const uiSchema = {
      "c1": {
        "ApplicantTitle": {
          "ui:widget": "text"
        },
        "ApplicantSurname": {
          "ui:widget": "text"
        },
        "ApplicantGender": {
          "ui:widget": "select"
        }
      },
      "c2": {
        "Tenure": {
          "ui:widget": "select"
        },
        "MovedToAddressDate": {
          "ui:widget": "date"
        }
      },
      "c3": {
        "Pregnant": {
          "ui:widget": "select"
        },
        "PregnantDueDate": {
          "ui:widget": "date"
        },
        "ParentGuardianChildUnder19": {
          "ui:widget": "select"
        },
      },
      "_unmapped": {
        "ApplicantForenames": {
          "ui:widget": "text"
        },
        "ApplicantDateOfBirth": {
          "ui:widget": "date"
        }
      }
    };

var result = [];
for(var key in uiSchema){
  result.push(uiSchema[key]);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yeah that looks like it, simple answer, I missed using the key, I've upped your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash, you can just use [`_.values`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#values) to get an array of all the object properties.

`var uiParsed = _.values(uiSchema);`

```js
    const uiSchema = {
          "c1": {
            "ApplicantTitle": {
              "ui:widget": "text"
            },
            "ApplicantSurname": {
              "ui:widget": "text"
            },
            "ApplicantGender": {
              "ui:widget": "select"
            }
          },
          "c2": {
            "Tenure": {
              "ui:widget": "select"
            },
            "MovedToAddressDate": {
              "ui:widget": "date"
            }
          },
          "c3": {
            "Pregnant": {
              "ui:widget": "select"
            },
            "PregnantDueDate": {
              "ui:widget": "date"
            },
            "ParentGuardianChildUnder19": {
              "ui:widget": "select"
            },
          },
          "_unmapped": {
            "ApplicantForenames": {
              "ui:widget": "text"
            },
            "ApplicantDateOfBirth": {
              "ui:widget": "date"
            }
          }
        }
    
    var uiParsed = _.values(uiSchema);
    
    console.log(uiParsed);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Object.values(uiSchema)`:

```js
const uiSchema = { "c1": { "ApplicantTitle": { "ui:widget": "text" }, "ApplicantSurname": { "ui:widget": "text" }, "ApplicantGender": { "ui:widget": "select" } }, "c2": { "Tenure": { "ui:widget": "select" }, "MovedToAddressDate": { "ui:widget": "date" } }, "c3": { "Pregnant": { "ui:widget": "select" }, "PregnantDueDate": { "ui:widget": "date" }, "ParentGuardianChildUnder19": { "ui:widget": "select" }, }, "_unmapped": { "ApplicantForenames": { "ui:widget": "text" }, "ApplicantDateOfBirth": { "ui:widget": "date" } } };

console.log(Object.values(uiSchema));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

The community always expects you to show some effort before asking for answers. hope you understand.

```js
let uiSchema = {
      "c1": {
        "ApplicantTitle": {
          "ui:widget": "text"
        },
        "ApplicantSurname": {
          "ui:widget": "text"
        },
        "ApplicantGender": {
          "ui:widget": "select"
        }
      },
      "c2": {
        "Tenure": {
          "ui:widget": "select"
        },
        "MovedToAddressDate": {
          "ui:widget": "date"
        }
      },
      "c3": {
        "Pregnant": {
          "ui:widget": "select"
        },
        "PregnantDueDate": {
          "ui:widget": "date"
        },
        "ParentGuardianChildUnder19": {
          "ui:widget": "select"
        },
      },
      "_unmapped": {
        "ApplicantForenames": {
          "ui:widget": "text"
        },
        "ApplicantDateOfBirth": {
          "ui:widget": "date"
        }
      }
    }

let keys = Object.keys(uiSchema);
let uiParsed = [];
for(i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
   uiParsed.push(uiSchema[keys[i]])
}
console.log(uiParsed);
```